# Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftCore.dylibon devices

Tags: xcode, swift, dylib

My code runs perfect on simulators, but not on device.

I get this error:

> dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftCore.dylib
>     Referenced from: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/1A779F82-B55D-48BE-870E-282EE7167B98/TabletPLUS.app/TabletPLUS
>     Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
>     /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/1A779F82-B55D-48BE-870E-282EE7167B98/TabletPLUS.app/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib: mmap() error 1 at address=0x100CD0000, size=0x0015C000 segment=__TEXT in Segment::map() mapping /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/1A779F82-B55D-48BE-870E-282EE7167B98/TabletPLUS.app/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib

I have revoked the distribution and development certificate and added the new one too.

But returning me the same error.

I am trying with iPad Air.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I had to format my Mac and install it fresh..After  that i worked..

Answer (score 0):

Just delete the application in your device and run it again.